Query on deploying Spring 5.x application in Tomcat 10 ? is there any backward compatibility for Tomcat 10 to support Spring 5.x application?
Our application is developed using latest Spring 5.x jars and currently it is working fine in Tomcat 9.x application server. we are getting compilation errors when trying to deploy the application in Tomcat 10.x app server. Is there any backward compatibility for Tomcat 10.x application server to still support Spring 5.x application
we tried deploying our application into Tomcat 10.x server but it is giving compilation problem. we are aware that we should be upgrading our application to Spring 6.x with JDK 17 but we would like to know if there is any possibility to use Tomcat 10.x for Spring 5.x application

Could you please edit the question to include some of the error output and the relevant lines of code? For readability put both error output and code in blocks delimited by triple-back-ticks.

I think we cannot use JDK 17 with Spring 5.x and Tomcat 9.x.
